# Creating Camel routes at runtime in Grails

Tags: configuration, grails, apache-camel

The [Grails routing plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/routing) makes creating Apache Camel routes at compile-time trivial.  Is there a way to create new routes at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here for a complete walk-through: [Grails, Camel and adding routes at runtime](http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2011/01/grails-camel-and-adding-routes-in.html)

Comment: Thanks @Matthias - that's just the ticket.  I'd tried getting hold of CamelContext before, but hadn't got it to work (perhaps the autowiring was broken, or perhaps I was doing something stupid).  Would it be possible to add details from your blog post to this answer so that the details are available on SO?

Answer (score 2):

Camel has API for creating and adding routes at runtime.

For example loading routes from XML
http://camel.apache.org/loading-routes-from-xml-files.html

And you can also use the API from the model package or use a RouteBuilder instance and define your routes. Then just use the API on CamelContext to add routes.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin was only released a couple of days ago - your best bet is to ask the plugin developers.

Comment: @Butt Wow! Thanks for the tip. Any idea best way to get in touch? grails-users mailing list?

Comment: Sure, the mailing list is probably best. The author email(s) are usually in the plugin descriptor, in this case RoutingGrailsPlugin.groovy: http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-routing/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/RoutingGrailsPlugin.groovy